# Monitoring Windows Servers Remotely (via Web Interface)

Tags: javascript, php, html, snmp

I would like to create a webpage that will display if a server is up or down. The servers are all Windows however some are 2008 and some are 2003, they are hosted inside different networks at various clients. I would like to setup a webpage with a matrix showing the status of each server. I have been looking into SNMP to do this however is seems to complicated for what I want to setup.

How would I go about checking if a server is up and maybe even sending out a notification if a server goes down all while displaying it on a webpage on a VPS LAMP stack.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this question help you.. [Monit windows OS.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/663780/any-monit-like-equivalents-for-windows-os

Answer (score 1):

I'd choose Nagios, it's free for small environments (7 nodes max) : http://www.nagios.org/